# SQL: Setting MaxFieldSize in ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, resultset

I'm trying to set `setMaxFieldSize(<int>)` to truncate column values to 512 bytes, however it just doesn't seem to have any effect on the returned rows when I iterate over the `ResultSet`. Also, I'm able to get `setMaxRows()` to work.

The 'sample' table has 8 rows and by setting `setMaxRows(1)`, I am able to limit the rows returned to 1 when I iterate over the `ResultSet` (just can't get `setMaxFieldSize()` to work). Also, I cannot modify the underlying table.

Here is my SQL (Ideally, I wouldn't want to edit the SQL query itself and would prefer truncating strings > 512 bytes (1 char = 1 byte) using the ResultSet function listed above):

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`, `col6`, `col7`, `col8`, `col9` 
FROM `sample` LIMIT 1000

col1 - col7 are of Type LONGVARCHAR (-1: java.sql.Types)
col8 is of Type CHAR (1: java.sql.Types)
col9 is of Type VARCHAR (12: java.sql.Types)
```

According to the Java doc, the above fields should get truncated as they are in the list of supported fields:

> This limit applies only to BINARY, VARBINARY, LONGVARBINARY, CHAR,
>   VARCHAR, NCHAR, NVARCHAR, LONGNVARCHAR and LONGVARCHAR fields.

Here is the my code ("java.sql.Connection connection" is passed in as a parameter to the function):

```
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
try {
    stmt = connection.createStatement();
    stmt.setMaxFieldSize(4);
    stmt.setMaxRows(1);
    resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    System.out.println(stmt.getMaxFieldSize() + " MaxFS");

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("ROW_DETAILS: " + resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + ", " + resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(i) + ", " + 
                                resultSet.getString(i).length() + ", " + resultSet.getString(i));
        }
    }
}
....
....
```

Output (note that col8 and col9 are of different types and with lesser text):

```
ROW_DETAILS: col1, -1, 2664, <text>
ROW_DETAILS: col2, -1, 2664, <text>
ROW_DETAILS: col3, -1, 2664, <text>
ROW_DETAILS: col4, -1, 2664, <text>
ROW_DETAILS: col5, -1, 2664, <text>
ROW_DETAILS: col6, -1, 2664, <text>
ROW_DETAILS: col7, -1, 2664, <text>
ROW_DETAILS: col8, 1, 255, <text>
ROW_DETAILS: col9, 12, 550, <text>
```

My intention is to truncate the lengths of each of the above column values returned in the row output to 512 using setMaxFieldSize but unfortunately, the length is always set to its original.

Comment: The chance is high it simply isn't implemented (check the MySQL Connector/J sources if you want to be sure), as this is a rather awkward feature of JDBC that has no practical use (ie: limit traffic) unless the database-specific protocol itself allows for this feature. If you want to limit columns for presentation purposes, you can do that yourself.

Comment: You didn't mention the versions of `MySQL` DB you are using and the version of Connector/J driver you are using?